# jQuery get selector string from an object

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="one">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Now, as we see there is one container with three children within it.

My question is, If I click the **second** div child, how can I get an alert message with the proper selector?

Something like `'body div#one:nth-child(2)'`, or something similar.

Hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you planning to do with the selector? I can't think of any circumstances where a selector would be more useful than `this`.

Comment: Why do you need to know the CSS selector?  I'm pretty sure there's no easy way to get it.

Comment: do you need a generalized function or a page specific function? also, is it important the way you get the selectors? it could be by id, class or tag. There are many things to consider to do a generalized function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#one').children().click(function(){
    alert('item : '+$(this).index()+" html: "+$(this).html()); // Will alert current child's index and html   
});​
```

An example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qENw9/3/).

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
$("#one div").click(function(){
  alert($(this));
});
```

You can alert content :

```
alert($(this).html());
```